# Runtime error when passing string into boolean function to scan file for an identical string

Tags: java, boolean, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, filereader

Part of the program I am creating requires a check to see if the same string (Indicating a product's ID code) has already been written into a text file. This is to stop the same ID being written in twice.

I am using a Boolean method which passes in a string from the GUI user input, and then compares it to every already existing line in the file.

The method is below.

```
public boolean hasIDAlreadyBeenUsed(String IDBeingTested) {
        boolean Decision = false;
        String ID = "Product ID: "+IDBeingTested;
        BufferedReader theBR;
        Scanner scanner;
        String scannedString;
        try {
            theBR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ProductData.txt"));
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("ProductData.txt"));

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                scannedString = scanner.nextLine();

                String character = scanner.findInLine(ID);


                if ((character) == (ID)) {
                    Decision = true;
                    System.out.println("they are a match: " + ID);

                } else {
                    Decision = false;
                }
            }
            theBR.close();
            theBR = null;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Decision = false;
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }

        return Decision;
    }
```

if the boolean returns a false, the data will be written into the file, if it returns a true an error message will appear and no data is written.

Below is the code that relies upon the boolean output.

```
private void jAddProductToDatabseButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                           


        if (!product.hasIDAlreadyBeenUsed(jProductIDTextField.getText())) {
            try {
                BufferedWriter ProductFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ProductData.txt", true));

                ProductFileWriter.write("Product Name: " + jProductNameTextField.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.write("Product ID: " + jProductIDTextField.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.write("Product Weight: " + jProductWeightTextField.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.write("Product Selling Price (£): " + jProductSellingPriceTextField.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.write("Product Image File Name: " + jNameOfImageFileTextField.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.write("Product Manufacturer Address: " + jManufacturerAddressTextArea.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.write("Product Type: " + jProductTypeTextField.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.write("Product Unit Cost: " + jProductUnitCostTextField.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.write("Product Delivery Time: " + jProductDeliveryTimeTextField.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.write("Product Shelf Life: " + jProductShelfLifeTextField.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.write("Product Stock Level: " + jInitialStockLevelTextField.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.write("==============================" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                ProductFileWriter.flush();
                ProductFileWriter.close();
                ProductFileWriter = null;
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {}

        } 
        else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot input, ID HAS ALREADY BEEN USED", "Incorrect ID", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

However the else statement is never executed, even if the same number e.g 44 has been entered as ID multiple times.

I even used this inside to show that the strings were the same. and the same string is produced twice.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            scannedString = scanner.nextLine();

            String character = scanner.findInLine(ID);
            System.out.println(scannedString);
            System.out.println("Product ID: " + ID);
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: will bear in mind in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to break loop once you found match, otherwise `Decision` value being overwritten for next line.

```
public static boolean hasIDAlreadyBeenUsed(String IDBeingTested) {
    boolean Decision = false;
    String ID = "Product ID:" + IDBeingTested;

    Scanner scanner;
    String scannedString;
    try {

        scanner = new Scanner(new File("src/ProductData.txt"));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            scannedString = scanner.nextLine();

            if (scannedString.equalsIgnoreCase(ID)) {

                Decision = true;
                System.out.println("they are a match: " + ID);
                break;

            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Decision = false;
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }

    return Decision;
}
```

Also i don't think you need findInLine method here. I hove this will solve your problem. Use file path according to your project structure.

Note:: It is good if we follow naming conventions in code.

Comment: this is worked , thanks so much. can you please clarify that src simply means the name of the file path ? or is this incorrect ?

Comment: src is the folder in which file is stored.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is coming from this statement:

```
if ((character) == (ID)) {
```

This compares if the String objects are the same.

Using the following:

```
if (character.equals(ID)){
```

should compare the value of the Strings instead.

Comment: I have ran the code like this and receive the following error,

"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException,

Would you know how to resolve this ?

Comment: The Strings I am trying to compare are for example "Product ID: 4" with "Product ID: 4".. so I think the reason I get the error is because Its trying to derive a numerical value from a string. do you know if I am correct ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using Scanner and BufferedReader, in your case either can be used but both are not required to solve your issue.
You can try something snippet like.

```
public static boolean hasIDAlreadyBeenUsed(String IDBeingTested) throws IOException {
        boolean Decision = false;
        String ID = "Product ID: "+IDBeingTested;
        BufferedReader theBR = null;
        String scannedString;
        try {
            theBR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ProductData.txt"));

            while ((scannedString=theBR.readLine())!=null) {
                if(!Decision)
                    Decision = scannedString.contains(ID);
                else
                    break;
            }
        } finally {
            theBR.close();
        }

        return Decision;
    }
```

Also a tip I would like to give, Don't start the variable name with Capital letter(Usually Classes have the first letter in capital). You can refer some online tutorial for good programming practices.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Change your comparison code to the following in hasIDAlreadyBeenUsed() method:

```
String character = scanner.findInLine(ID);

if ((character.trim().equals(ID)) { // by trimming I'm removing the line separator and then use equals to do a string comparision.
    Decision = true;
    System.out.println("they are a match: " + ID);
} else {
    Decision = false;
}
```